# Jquery Slide a div to the left on hover and collaspe on mouseout not working as it should?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, onmouseover

Hi I was wondering if I could get help with finishing this piece of code,

I have a div with overflow:hidden and a margin-left of 82px, inside it is one share link and then a ul list with three external links,

When I hover over the share link it works fine, as in the div slides to the left back to margin-left: 0.

However I want this to collapse again when I mouseout of the parent div not just the share link, this is causing problems, as when I put the mouseout functionality in it means that when you move over the ul list of links the whole thing slides everywhere and is very usable.

What I basically need is when a link is hovered over, the div will slide to the left letting three links appear and the user can click on these, then when the user moves away from the div it collapse's again.

Here is my jquery code so far:

```
$("#shareBtn").mouseover(function(){
        var $marginLefty = $(this).parent();
    $marginLefty.animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 40) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
        var $marginLefty = $(this).parent();
    $marginLefty.animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 40) == 82 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 82
    });
});
```

and the html to go with it:

```
 <div id="player">


   <div id="share_feature">
      <div>
        <a id="shareBtn" href="#">share</a>
        <ul id="player_social">
            <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is many examples out there about this topic.

use something like this:

```
$("#shareBtn").bind('mouseenter mouseleave',function(event){
    var $marginLefty = $(this).parent();
    if(event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $marginLefty.animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 40) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });    
    } else if(event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $marginLefty.animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 40) == 82 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 82
        });    
    } 
});
```

i haven't tested it, but with this one, you are saving extra looking for `$(this).parent()` and it should do what you need

Answer (score 1):

Try this along with your code which will collapse the div back once you move out of it.

```
$("#share_feature").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($(this).css('marginLeft'), 40) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
  });
})
```